# How to change/set/manage borders between sections in uicollectionview?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to build application with typical DataGrid inside. I have already built customCollectionViewLayout which displays data in DataGrid as you can see in attached picture ([application screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOavu.png)). Every row is a section in CollectionView. I've added border (1.0f) to every cell, but I can't manage border size between sections - it also needs to be 1.0f, but now the border width is duplicated, because items are in different sections.

Could you please help me and advice how to set border between sections also equal to 1.0f?

Answer (score 0):

Just Use the predefined delegate methods definitely it willIf work.
Still if you are facing problem in adjusting the border between the cell, design the **custom cell** like bellow picture. 
[image]

It will creates the space between the cells automatically then you can design the cell border as per your requirement.

Comment: Could you please write what exactly predefined method should I use?